# Sums of morphisms in abelian categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an abelian category and let $A,B,C,D$ be objects. For two morphisms $f:A \to B$ and $g:C \to D$, do we have a uniquely/canonically defined morphism
$$
f \oplus g: A \oplus C \to B \oplus D?
$$

Comment: Yes. This is the definition of $\oplus$ being a [bifunctor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bifunctor), which is part of the definition of "abelian category"

Comment: How is $\oplus$ being a bifunctor part of the definition of an abelian category? Does it follow from additive, or pre-additive, pre-abelian, . . .  ?

Comment: It's part of the definition of $\oplus$ being a biproduct. It's a functor from $\mathcal{M} \times \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$. That's part of what it means to be either a product or a coproduct. In particular, that's part of what it means to be a biproduct.

Comment: Does this mean that we have a bifunctor whenever all products, or all coproduces exist?

Comment: Yep! That's exactly right ^_^. In general $\times$ and $+$ (product and coproduct) are bifunctors (in particular, they have actions on arrows like you're asking for here)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Where can I see a detailed explanation of this? I don\t see that it follows from the definition of byproduct.

Comment: It is explained here: https://stackunderflow.dev/p/note-on-bifunctors/